# При помощи каких методов API Яндекс карт можно сделать Карту маршрута?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Пример: https://rasp.yandex.ru/thread/R_160A_112, далее нажать кнопку "Карта маршрута"

Как сделать такое?

В частности, мне нужно нанести на карту несколько маршрутов поездов

Comment: Никак. Ж/д маршрутизации у Яндекса нет. Даже если их Расписание и использует данные Карт, это внутренние методы "для своих", не публичные.

Comment: ...ну разве что самому нарисовать ломаные по железной дороге, если нужно лишь несколько маршрутов.